# BuddyPress add custom class to profile page buttons

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, buddypress

I am trying to create a custom theme for BuddyPress and in the template the buddypress/members/single/member-header.php file at line 45 there are buttons rendered using `<?php do_action( 'bp_member_header_actions' ); ?>`

After a lot of searching around I found out that I should be able to use filters to add custom data to elements, the problem is that I can't find anywhere as to what filter to use or how to  use such a filter to add a custom class to these buttons.

The buttons I am talking about are the buttons like "Add Friend", "Public Message" and "Private Message" and I would like to add the "btn" class.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out these filters:

```
bp_get_add_friend_button
bp_get_send_public_message_button
bp_get_send_message_button_args
```

EDIT: Updated (see comments)

Comment: I think you meant the bp_get_send_private_message_button, but for some strange reason that one changes nothing

Comment: Oops, apologies. I actually mean't bp_get_send_message_button_args. Please see my edit.

Comment: I wonder who thought that would be a better name then the bp_get_send_private_message_button.. anyhow, it works, thanks

Comment: My guess is public messaging and friendships were introduced at a different time to private messaging - which might explain why the naming is inconsistent